# How to ssh in to a blowfish-based server from MacOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, command-line, ssh, compatibility

We've got some embedded devices that we need to ssh in to sometimes in order to administer, but the devices' ssh server only supports the "blowfish" cypher.

This has been working okay, except that for MacOS 10.12 Sierra, Apple has removed support for the Blowfish algorithm, meaning that MacOS's built-in command-line ssh client will no longer connect to this device.

Given that we can't (easily) upgrade the embedded device to use a different cypher, what would be our best approach to connecting to this device from a Sierra-based Mac?  Is there some other ssh client we could use instead, or some way to re-enable blowfish support for the built-in client?

Answer (score 1):

Manual page for `ssh` explains the `-c` switch, which is used for the cipher specification:

```
ssh -c blowfish-cbc your_host
```

should do the job.

Comment: > Apple has removed support for the Blowfish algorithm, meaning that MacOS's built-in command-line ssh client will no longer connect to this device.